# list of redirects not working

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I've got a list of redirects that isn't working. I'm redirecting 1 domain to another. There are about 10 pages that I have want redirected to unique pages. The rest I want redirected to the home page.

Currently, it redirects everything to the home page including these location pages.

Thoughts?

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
# Redirect individual store pages to NewSoundHearing.com
RewriteRule ^/about-us/eugene-or$  http://www.newsoundhearing.com/locations/eugene/ [L,R=301,NC]
RewriteRule ^/about-us/gearhart-or$  http://www.newsoundhearing.com/locations/gearhart/ [L,R=301,NC]
RewriteRule ^/about-us/gresham-or$  http://www.newsoundhearing.com/locations/gresham/ [L,R=301,NC]
RewriteRule ^/about-us/king-city-or$  http://www.newsoundhearing.com/locations/king-city/ [L,R=301,NC]
RewriteRule ^/about-us/mcminnville%20-%20or$  http://www.newsoundhearing.com/locations/mcminnville/ [L,R=301,NC]
RewriteRule ^/about-us/north-bend-or$  http://www.newsoundhearing.com/locations/north-bend/ [L,R=301,NC]
RewriteRule ^/about-us/north-plains-or$  http://www.newsoundhearing.com/locations/north-plains/ [L,R=301,NC]
RewriteRule ^/about-us/oregon-city-or$  http://www.newsoundhearing.com/locations/oregon-city/ [L,R=301,NC]
RewriteRule ^/about-us/portland-or$ http://www.newsoundhearing.com/locations/portland/ [L,R=301,NC]
RewriteRule ^/about-us/west-portland-or$ http://www.newsoundhearing.com/locations/portland-west/ [L,R=301,NC]
RewriteRule ^/about-us/salem-or$ http://www.newsoundhearing.com/locations/salem/ [L,R=301,NC]
RewriteRule ^/about-us/vancouver-wa$ http://www.newsoundhearing.com/locations/vancouver/ [L,R=301,NC]
# Redirect everything else to NewSoundHearing.com
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ http://www.newsoundhearing.com/ [R=301,NC]
```

Comment: Thanks for commenting. Tried that on the first couple locations. Didn't work. Still redirects to home page.

Comment: If you take out the default rule (i.e. the one the redirects everything else), do your first set of rules fire? (also... are both your domains running on the same server?  I'd wonder if you aren't getting double redirected... as in, if you go to http://myserver/about-us/gresham, you get redirected to http://www.newsound.com/locations/gresham, which then gets redirected to http://www.newsound.com/ if your rewrite is global and not just for the other domain)

Comment: If I comment out catch all, nothing redirects with www URLS. On non-www URLS, it returns "Forbidden"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Remove leading slash from rule pattern
2. In last rule redirect everything except `/locations` to avoid redirecting top URLs again.

Have your rules like this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

# Redirect individual store pages to NewSoundHearing.com
RewriteRule ^about-us/eugene-or$ /locations/eugene/ [L,R=301,NC]
RewriteRule ^about-us/gearhart-or$ /locations/gearhart/ [L,R=301,NC]
RewriteRule ^about-us/gresham-or$ /locations/gresham/ [L,R=301,NC]
RewriteRule ^about-us/king-city-or$ /locations/king-city/ [L,R=301,NC]
RewriteRule ^about-us/mcminnville%20-%20or$ /locations/mcminnville/ [L,R=301,NC]
RewriteRule ^about-us/north-bend-or$ /locations/north-bend/ [L,R=301,NC]
RewriteRule ^about-us/north-plains-or$ /locations/north-plains/ [L,R=301,NC]
RewriteRule ^about-us/oregon-city-or$ /locations/oregon-city/ [L,R=301,NC]
RewriteRule ^about-us/portland-or$ /locations/portland/ [L,R=301,NC]
RewriteRule ^about-us/west-portland-or$ /locations/portland-west/ [L,R=301,NC]
RewriteRule ^about-us/salem-or$ /locations/salem/ [L,R=301,NC]
RewriteRule ^about-us/vancouver-wa$ /locations/vancouver/ [L,R=301,NC]

# Redirect everything else to NewSoundHearing.com
RewriteRule !^locations/ http://www.newsoundhearing.com/ [R=301,L,NC]
```

Comment: Thanks! That did it. I had to add to full URL to the destination, but removing the leading slashes and excluding ^locations/ was the key. Thanks again!

Comment: Marked as answered. Thanks again.